# How to get parent observation on Spring Boot 3 using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm migrating some REST applications to Spring Boot 3 and I'm trying to set an extra low cardinality key/value, based on the value of an incoming request header (X-Traffic-Type).

When doing it for webflux applications, everything works fine: I provide an extension of `DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention` and set the value based on the incoming header:

```java
public class MyCustomServerRequestObservationConvention extends DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention {

    @Override
    public KeyValues getLowCardinalityKeyValues(final ServerRequestObservationContext context) {
        return super.getLowCardinalityKeyValues(context).and(KeyValue.of(SupplyHubMetricsAutoConfiguration.TRAFFIC_TYPE_TAG, getTrafficType(context.getCarrier())));
    }

    private String getTrafficType(final ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeaders().getFirst("X-Traffic-Type"))
                       .map(String::toLowerCase)
                       .orElse("");
    }
}
```

For the client side, I can simply get the traffic type from the parent observation on an extension of `DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention`:

```java
public class MyCustomClientRequestObservationConvention extends DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention {

    @Override
    public KeyValues getLowCardinalityKeyValues(final ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
        return KeyValues.of(method(context), status(context), exception(context), outcome(context), trafficType(context), qualifier(context));
    }

    protected KeyValue trafficType(ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
        String trafficType = Optional.ofNullable(context.getParentObservation())
                                     .map(ObservationView::getContextView)
                                     .map(e -> e.getLowCardinalityKeyValue(TRAFFIC_TYPE_TAG))
                                     .map(KeyValue::getValue)
                                     .orElse(DEFAULT_TRAFFIC_TYPE);
        return KeyValue.of(TRAFFIC_TYPE_TAG, trafficType);
    }

}
```

Now, when I do the same for the MVC applications, I can set the value on the server observation but when I implement the client part by extending `DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention` the observation doesn't have a parent observation (which I'm expecting to be the server one):

```java
public class MyCustomClientRequestObservationConvention extends DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention {

    @Override
    public KeyValues getLowCardinalityKeyValues(final ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
        return KeyValues.of(method(context), status(context), exception(context), outcome(context), trafficType(context), qualifier());
    }


    protected KeyValue trafficType(ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
        // context.getParentObservation() always returns null
        String trafficType = Optional.ofNullable(context.getParentObservation())
                                     .map(ObservationView::getContextView)
                                     .map(e -> e.getLowCardinalityKeyValue(TRAFFIC_TYPE_TAG))
                                     .map(KeyValue::getValue)
                                     .orElse(DEFAULT_TRAFFIC_TYPE);
        return KeyValue.of(TRAFFIC_TYPE_TAG, trafficType);
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? what's the reason why webflux observations keep the hierarchy but mvc ones seems not to?